# How to show multiple components in a specific position inside of a parent component in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to render multiple components inside of a parent component on a specific position (based on some calculations). The calculations that give me the vertical position look correct, but the components are not displayed in the position they should. I have tried both absolute window position and relative component position with no luck.

The parent looks like follows:

```
const top = 170;
const bottom = 10;
const left = 10;
const right = 10;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  grid: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: top,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height - top - bottom,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - left - right,
    borderLeftColor: 'black',
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
});

const DrawGrid: React.FC<IDrawGrid> = ({ maxDistance, elements }) => {
  const [gridSize, setGridSize] = useState<LayoutRectangle>();

  return (
    <View style={styles.grid} onLayout={(event) => {
      setGridSize(event.nativeEvent.layout);
    }}>
      {elements.map((element, index) => {
        return (
          <DrawElement element={element} maxDistance={maxDistance} gridSize={gridSize} index={index * 2} />
        )
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

And the child component that renders all the elements looks like follows:

```
const top = 170;
const bottom = 20;
const left = 10;
const right = 10;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  elementContainer: {
    borderLeftColor: 'red',
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'red',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderRightColor: 'red',
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 2,
    position: 'relative',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  }
});

const getVerticalPosition = (someDistance: number, maxDistance: number, height: number) => {
  if (!someDistance || !maxDistance) return { top: 0 };

  const topDistance = (1 - (someDistance / maxDistance)) * height;
  return { top: topDistance };
};

const DrawElement: React.FC<IDrawElement> = ({ maxDistance, element, gridSize, index }) => {
  const styleVertical = getVerticalPosition(someDistance, maxDistance, gridSize.height);

  return (
    <View key={key} style={[styles.elementContainer, styleVertical]}>
      <Text>top: {styleVertical.top.toFixed(2)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I can see how `getVerticalPosition` returns the right value, but the element is never located in the position expected. In the snapshot below I am printing the top value for each element, and we can see it is not respected at all. (horizontal location is out of the scope of the problem)
[image]
My first thought was that I am messing up the styles somehow, I also tried giving a different `zindex` to each element without luck. Any ideas what could happen? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some visual example how it looks like? Or provide interactive example in code sandbox.

Comment: I just uploaded a snapshot of what I see on my device, sorry about that

Comment: I really don't undestand why you set alignSelf and relative position. I would take off alignSelf and set position to absolute.

Comment: alignSelf helps making the component as big as its content is. If I remove it, the problem locating the component vertically is not fixed. I use position relative because I want the children to be placed in a position relative to the parent. I have also tried calculating the absolute position but that does not solve the problem either...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand how the layout type works in React Native. Here is a link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#absolute--relative-layout. The main problem is `relative` position for each child element related to its own initial position.

By default, all elements in React Native have `position` equal to `relative`, so you don't need to put it in style definition.

To better understanding `relative` position scheme, I suggest you consider its rendering process in two steps:

1. rendering children without any of `top, left, bottom, right` properties;
2. shifting children according to their `top, left, bottom, right` properties from their current positions;

Imagine that you have such code:

```
<View style={styles.parent}>
  <View style={styles.firstChild}/>
  <View style={styles.secondChild}/>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
    top: 100,
    flex: 1,
  },
  firstChild: {
    top: 100,
    height: 50,
  },
  secondChild: {
    top: 80,
    height: 70,
  },
});
```

If we apply two steps mentioned above to this example it will look like this:

[image]   [image]

To solve your problem you need to apply `absolute` position scheme to children. Only `absolute` position scheme place element, with for example `top: 100` property, to  100 points down related to the current top of its parent.

I hope it will help you a little.